# Most visible wavelength/ color for mesopic vision

Tags: accessibility, physical, light

Is there an established study that demonstrates which is the most visible wavelength range under [Mesopic Vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesopic_vision) conditions? Ideally, they shouldn't refer to Scotopic Vision (since I have enough data for that condition), but urban mesopic conditions for night light with disruptive factors like rain, snow, fog, hail, or abundant flora.

**Additional (if possible):** wavelength frequencies that are effective in light emitters between 3 and 10 cd / m2 (approximately the [brightness of ambulance lights](https://www.ojp.gov/pdffiles1/Digitization/52417NCJRS.pdf))

Basically, I'm trying to find a light color with the above mentioned conditions but that it's not red, green, blue or yellow (or orange or purple). I was thinking of a turquoise gamma, but can't find any information to support this election and have no way to test this by myself.

Comment: [looking at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesopic_vision) and [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22541/#:%7E:text=Section%2032.3Photoreceptor%20Molecules%20in,850%20nm%20(Figure%2032.19).) I would say anywhere from 500nm to 550nm seems to be your sweet spot so cyan to light green. However I am a long way out of my comfort zone so I could be misreading the data!

Comment: yes @GrahamRitchie, that's why I though of the turquoise color. However, it's not clear if it acts the same on urban mesopic conditions since both green and blue could be confused with may sources of light built with that exact purpose: to be seen at night. Also, the disruptive factors are very important since some wavelengths lose visibility by replicating themselves (for example, if you see white light in fog conditions, you'll see a huge amount of diffuse light, while blue will be more concentrated in a source)

Answer (score 1):

[is this article at all useful?](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22541/#:%7E:text=Section%2032.3Photoreceptor%20Molecules%20in,850%20nm%20(Figure%2032.19).)

From a quick glance it appears that rods absorb light most effectively around 500nm which is a cyan / light green colour. However I only scan read it and it has been many many years since I did biology and physics so I could be very wrong!

[image: colour spectrum to highlight 500nm colour (cyan / green)]